# Mysterious horizontal lines on my site when rendered on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, safari

The following site:

http://staging.jungledragon.com

Has a few rendering issues on the iPad using Safari, so I'm trying to fix them. There is one issue where I am stuck though. If you have an iPad, open the site in portrait mode. There are two unwanted horizontal lines appearing, a top one that crosses the tabs (Popular, Fresh, etc) and a bottom one that sits right above the lizard illustration. Both lines should not be there.

These lines do not appear on any other browser tested, including Safari on Windows. When you move that same site into landscape mode on the iPad, the top horizontal line dissapears, whilst the bottom one stays. If you zoom in a bit to the bottom line, it then dissapears too.

I've been trying out various CSS fixes to no avail and am now beginning to think this is a rendering issue of Safari, although possibly triggered by me.

**Any help is greatly appreciated. It seems like a minor issue but I hate sloppiness.**

Comment: conditional bad pixels? ;) [seriously - looking into it. try some tools like firebug to identify if it's not a border of an element]

Comment: see if fiddling with table attributes in main.css, line 12 helps. Remove those 2 lines present and put black border definition there. then see if you see lines.

Comment: The locations that you describe is the locations of the top and bottom portion of the #content `div`, I'm guessing it's not a coincidence.

Comment: BTW. A screenshot would be useful. Not a lot of people bought those iPads, you know ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oops - how did that happen?

The meta to go in the head tag to to stop zooming on the iPad:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: As noted below this takes away user control over the viewport, which in most cases should be avoided.

Answer (score 9):

The issue's have to do with the way Mobile Safari handles background images. The green line that pops up (just inside your content area) is from another element.

Try 'over sizing' your images. For instance: A image gets cut off at 100 pixel height, make that image 110 pixels high. This works for me... most of the time.

Edit: I did check the site on my iPad and I just saw that single line popping up. Also note that it disappears when you zoom in/out which tells me it's a rendering bug (not something in your css).

Comment: By the way, when I say it's the way Mobile Safari 'handles' background images, I mean it's a bug.

Comment: Intuition tells me it might be possible to fix it with `background-position` redefining the defaults as pixels or percents

Comment: Thank you so much Damien, there is no way I would have figured this out myself. I was able to get rid of the top line by increasing the height of the background image with a few pixels.

Comment: Sorry for the 2 comments, pressed enter which triggered the submit. The second line was removed by removing the background color of the footer, which I used in combination with a background image. The changes are working on my dev environment so you cannot see them at the above URL yet.

Comment: I think this is the best solution because it doesn't disable zooming, which is pretty essential functionality when using a tablet.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to specify the size of the background. This can be done with the css selector "background-size".

If your background image is 40 pixels high, the following code will prevent horizontal lines from showing up on the iPad: { background-size: 100% 40px }

Answer (score 1):

Over-sizing your background images manually or using CSS3 should almost always work, as Damien and namsral pointed out.

However, sometimes this will not solve the problem in cases where your background image is anchored at a certain position. For example, if your background image is anchored to the bottom of your div, and the line appears at the bottom of this div, then you should shift the background image lower [than the bottom] by a certain amount, depending on the height of your div. For example:

background-postion: center 100.1%;

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a css reset? If not try adding one it could be something standard for mobile devices to see if it still exists if it does check it out in firebug to see exactly what it is

Comment: Would have been better as a comment, as you're just guessing.

Comment: Thansk for thinking along, but yes, I always start my web projects with a CSS reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix a lot of these "iPad gaps" problems by disabling zooming entirely on the iPad, by use of this meta tag, a la Facebook:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

This prevents zooming on the iPad, but it has fixed all my "div gaps" problem completely.

Comment: It looks like some code or a link that you tried to paste in got lost. Can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

The background image I was using stops mid way through the content div and then the background of the container element is supposed to display.

Because the iPad zooms into the outermost div, the relevant background applied to the html tag isn't displayed. It seems that iPad doesn't like it when a fallback background color is not defined, so I had to add some iPad-specific CSS using a media query:

```
html { background:#ffffff url("images/bg-html.png") center top repeat-x; }
html#inside-html { background:#ffffff url("images/inside-bg-html.png") center top repeat-x; }

body { 
    background:transparent url("images/bg-body.jpg") center top no-repeat;
    text-align:center; 
    font:12px Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    line-height: 20px;
    color:#000;
    min-width: 980px;
}

body#inside { background: transparent url("images/inside-bg-body.jpg") center top no-repeat; }

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    body {
        background: #fff url("images/bg-body.jpg") center top no-repeat;
    }

    body#inside {
        background: #fff url("images/inside-bg-body.jpg") center top no-repeat;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cheers, I had the same but on Andriods and using the background-image:100% 460px; helped solve mine :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a span or div without any content in it.

Please give a `disply:none;` to this `div` or span and see the result.