# iPhone\iPad displaying thin lines after <div>. Negative margin doesn't solve the issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, rendering, lines

I'm facing a problem where a portal that I'm developing to serve pages for mobile devices doesn't display properly for iPhone - there appears some horizontal lines that I later found is a rendering issue. I've also got information that the lines also appear when viewed in Lumia 800, although I'm yet to test it in that device.

I've also went through threads discussing similar issues:
[Thin gray/black lines on web page viewed with iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780896/thin-gray-black-lines-on-web-page-viewed-with-ipad)
[Line artifacts in mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903106/line-artifacts-in-mobile-safari)
[Rendering borders bug in Safari mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015193/rendering-borders-bug-in-safari-mobile)
[Mysterious horizontal lines on my site when rendered on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225255/mysterious-horizontal-lines-on-my-site-when-rendered-on-ipad)

But most of them suggest using some way to reduce the margin by 1 or 2 pixels (negative margin) and use the same amount of padding to get it back.

```
.iosfix{  
margin-top: -1px;  
margin-bottom: -1px;  
padding-top: 1px;  
padding-bottom: 1px;  
}
```

But this exposes the background color, which is undesired.
I don't have the liberty to change the background color of such a div because in my requirement, the content to be displayed, the color styles, layout etc are dynamically built and I can't fiddle around with those changes.

I'm not able to post my exact code here, but I saw a very similar problem faced by another user posted in a different forum. The following is the site:
http://aaa.dev.energetica.com.au/
It renders properly in desktop browsers, but in the iPhone (I used the 3GS) horizontal lines were appearing.

1. Now that it is certain that its a browser issue with Mobile Safari and expecially considering iOS 6 has been launched, what is the official FIX for this issue that is not a 'compromise'?
2. Any iOS-specific tags to indicate the browser that it shouldn't apply the smoothening effect around the images?
3. In the case of nested divs, would applying a fix to the outermost div alone would suffice?

Would appreciate some assistance in solving the issue, Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution?